# Mann-Whitney U test using pandas groupby()

Tags: pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe similar to this one but with more samples and more data columns:

```
 data
          group    ADAM28  ADAM28.1  ADAM28.2       ADAM7
sample1     del  36.53930 -23.25650  -4.13008  -36.380600
sample2     del  -2.71788  29.80030   6.40632    1.939350
sample3     del  10.09880  -4.10111   6.82952   47.033500
sample4     del   5.19362   4.52109  -2.55278  134.387000
sample5     del  -5.86248  -4.22071   9.70282  -45.357800
sample6     del  26.75510  27.02110  -4.62898  111.514000
sample7   nodel -24.26460  11.76370 -19.17070    0.709847
sample8   nodel -23.24770  -3.52641 -14.89390  -46.733900
sample9   nodel  -6.77488 -22.98740  -2.09688  -11.281900
sample10  nodel  -3.98377  -4.27557   4.44730  -23.672000
sample11  nodel  -1.10222  -5.25087  -5.98834  -25.495100
sample12  nodel  -4.62463  -6.83067  -3.20250  -23.887400
```

I would like to do Mann-Whitney U tests for all columns based on "group", so something like:

```
data.groupby(["group"]).mannwhitneyu()
```

How do I call the data columns?

Comment: I'm not sure this is easily possible. `groupby` aggregation functions work within each group, not across groups, as you would need for a comparison test like Mann-Whitney.